# using SQL to save an output php webpage displayed to the server or

Tags: php, css, sql, html

I have two php files. One is my input php file is where I have heading title with a table. In the table, I have text, text boxes for writing text, and check boxes for putting check marks, and then it has a submit button to take me to the another php file which acts like my display output.

After I click on the submit button, It takes me to this output php file, which displays the same heading, same table structure with check marks that were inputted in input php file, and the text that was written in the input php file.

Now, I want a save button on the output php file, using SQL, that can save the entire output page displayed on a webpage, to be saved on my Linux server(that I have access to through my terminal) using file path, and/or also another save button on my output php file using SQL to save on my personal computer.

Example, this is my part of my input php file code:

```
<tr><td width="10" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="check_create_disk_array" value="Y"></td><td width="490" align="left">Create Disk Array</td><td width="1400" align="left"><input type="text" size="235" name="info_create_disk_array"></td></tr>`
```

this, is part of my output file code:

```
<tr><td width="10" align="left">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['check_create_disk_array']) && $_POST['check_create_disk_array'] == 'Y')
{
echo "Yes";
}
else
{
echo "No";
}
?>
</td>
<td width="290" align="left">Create Disk Array</td>
<td width="1600" align="left">
<?php
$info_create_disk_array = $_POST['info_create_disk_array'];
echo $info_create_disk_array;
?>
</td></tr>
```

Finally, Let us I put a checkmark and type 'terminator' in the textbox of the input php file, here would be the source code of the output webpage displaying(since I am not able to take pictures on my work computer or screen shots of the web page).

```
<tr>
<td width="10" align="left">
Yes</td>
<td width="290" align="left">Create Disk Array</td>
<td width="1600" align="left">
terminator</td>
</tr>
```

Earlier, I asked about if I can use Java Script seems like there is no way to do it, was wondering if I can use SQL to save the data inputted, and then use SQL to display the data on the output page.

Comment: _Javascript_ can't save this as a new file on the server — javascript can _send_ the new content _to_ the server, but then you'll need some piece of code on the server to receive that and save it. Since you're using PHP you would probably write that in PHP, but you could, for example, write that server-code in Javascript running under node (but then you're running two server programs on your server hardware)

Comment: What about JavaScript code for saving the output php page on my personal computer?